# Robotium tests in Android Honeycomb+

Tags: android, robotium

I have just started with Robotium and wrote a simple test:

```
public class TestLoginActivity extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {
    private static final String LOG = "TestLoginActivity";
    private Solo solo;

    public TestLoginActivity() {
        super(LoginActivity.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        solo = new Solo(new Instrumentation());
    }

    public void testPreferences(){
        Log.e(LOG, "0");
        getActivity();
        Log.e(LOG, "1 " + solo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().getName());
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("Check login activity", LoginActivity.class);
        Log.e(LOG, "2");
        solo.waitForActivity(LoginActivity.class);
        Log.e(LOG, "3");
        solo.clickOnView(solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(com.package.R.id.ic_settings));
        Log.e(LOG, "4");
        solo.waitForActivity(PrefsActivity.class);
        Log.e(LOG, "5");
        Log.e(LOG, solo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().getName());
        Log.e(LOG, "6");
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("Check " + solo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().getSimpleName(), PrefsActivity.class);
    }
}
```

I'm using constructor `Solo(Instrumentation instrumentation)` because with `Solo(Instrumentation instrumentation, Activity activity)` method `solo.getCurrentActivity()` returns previous activity. The problem is that right now, after `getActivity()` nothing happens. It waits 30s and then test fails.
Important thing is I have to use Android 3.0+

Comment: You're sure it's the `getActivity()` that causes the hang and not the `solo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().getName()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete your setUp code and use the following, without the teardown section getActivity() will return you the wrong activity.

```
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp()
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}
@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    super.tearDown();
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer because it's correct. Can you please explain me why it happens without teadDown()?

Comment: The reason is that your activity is still open, so the call to getActivity() just returns the activity that is current, closing the activity via the comands in teardown forces the next call to getActivity() to instead create a new activity of the type you gave in the constructor.